# Ajax pagination with plugins filters

Tags: php, ajax

i'm trying to add pagination.
I have already on my page a ajax filter plugin.
Here a part of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php
 //Database Connection
include ('lib/cfg.php');
include 'lib/fonctions.php';
$row_limit = 5;
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM figurines_deal");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetch();

// get total no. of pages
$total_pages = ceil($rows[0]/$row_limit);
?>

<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#show').click(function() {
              $('.price_filter').toggle("slide");
              $('.type_filter').toggle("slide");
              $('.annee_filter').toggle("slide");
              $('.marchand_filter').toggle("slide");

            });
        });
        </script>
......
<?php include "js/filter_promotion2.js" ?> // My js script to filtering results of my mysql request.
<div class="filter_data"> // This div displays the results of my mysql request
</div>

<div class="pagination"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pg-results").load("fetch_data.php");
    $(".pagination").bootpag({
        total: <?php echo $total_pages; ?>,
        page: 1,
        maxVisible: 5
    }).on("page", function(e, page_num){
        e.preventDefault();
        /*$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');*/
        $("#pg-results").load("fetch_data.php", {"page": page_num});
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

My ajax filter plugins works perfectly.
My pagination script without that ajax plugins works perfectly too.
But the 2 scripts doesn't works on the same page.
If i remove this line in the head 
`<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` and put it just before js script of pagination, the pagination works.

Whats' going wrong ? Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Did you hear about putting JS script files before the body closing tag, so the DOM can render faster?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ? The two plugins in the same page.